# ManagementScope and "root\cimv2"?

Tags: c#

To create a [`ManagementScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21xxae28.aspx) object you have to pass a string to the constructor which is either an IP address or the name of a PC.

What I don't get is what the last part is for:

```
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"FullComputerName\root\cimv2");
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
                                                               What is this?
```

What does `root\cimv2` stand for? Where does it come from? and what else could there be instead of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.aspx). That input parameter is the full path, meaning the folders leading to the file.

That particular path is the default namespace for [WMI classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389292%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Second link states it is the default namespace for Windows XP and Windows 2000.  It still is on windows 7 machine according to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WBEM\Scripting\Default Namespace.

Answer (score 19):

`root` is because it's the root of the tree. `cimv2` is actually `CIMv2`, because it's version 2 of the CIM (Common Information Model).